# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException?

Tags: java, hadoop, thrift, hive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828562/java-sql-sqlexception-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttransportexception-in-hive)

can you please tell me when this exception occurs? "org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException" Actually I want to store data into hive table with java. when I execute this code above exception occurs?

```
public void createTable(String tableName) {
    try{
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

    String QueryString = "INSERT INTO logs (id, msg) VALUES(1, 'hello')";

     a = stat.executeUpdate(QueryString);
    if(a==1){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("Table has been created");
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: Wait for an answer for this question, or update the question. Don't create the same question again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828562/java-sql-sqlexception-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttransportexception-in-hive

Comment: Can you add in the actual stack trace you are getting. Have you checked the logs on the hive side for any related errors, are you sure you have the same client and server library versions for hive