# Error in metadata: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, cloudera-cdh

What is this Error means?
"  Error in metadata: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException? "
In what are all the cases this error come?

I am getting this error while creating tables and while loading the data into the table.

Comment: Have you referred this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828562/java-sql-sqlexception-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttransportexception-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException, Its a very generic error that message describing that the hiveserver is having a problem and suggesting you to take a look at the Hive logs. If you can able to access the full log stack and share the exact details might get the real cause of this problem. Most of the times I faced this error was like Issues with hive metadata, unable to access hive metadata,dir permissions issues,concurrency related issues, hiveserver port related problems.

You can give a try restarting and recreating your tables. or setting up hive port before starting the server might help you.

```
    $export HIVE_PORT=10000
    $hive --service hiveserver
```

There might be other reasons too but we can look out there once we get full log stack.